# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'XXX' of undefined

Tags: javascript, database, oop

I'm giving JavaScript OOP a swirl for the first try and I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addWeight' of undefined

It is complaning about a method that is under `weight.webdb.addWeight` which is being called from a global function `addWeight`.

```
var weight = {};
weight.webdb = {};
weight.webdb.db = null;

weight.webdb.addWeight = function() {
    var db = weight.webdb.db;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var addedOn = new Date();
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO weight(input,comment,date) VALUES (?,?,?)', [inputWeight, inputComment, addedOn], weight.webdb.onSuccess, weight.webdb.onError);
    });
};

function addWeight(){
    var weight = document.getElementById('inputWeight');
    var comment = document.getElementById('inputComment');  
    weight.webdb.addWeight(weight.value,comment.value); 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SMbL3/1/

Comment: What's `webdb`? Oh, I have to open the fiddle just to see what you're talking about? In any case, how are you associating the DOM element with your arbitrarily-named object?

Comment: What makes you think that the "inputWeight" DOM element has a "webdb" property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local variable `weight` defined in the function is shadowing the `weight` variable in the outer scope. Just call the function-local variable something else, like `weight_elem`:

```
function addWeight() {
    var weight_elem = document.getElementById('inputWeight');
    var comment_elem = document.getElementById('inputComment');  
    weight.webdb.addWeight(weight_elem.value, comment_elem.value); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly states, `weight.webdb` does not exist.
`weight` is the local DOM element, not the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var weight = document.getElementById('inputWeight');
var comment = document.getElementById('inputComment');  
weight.webdb.addWeight(weight.value,comment.value);
//^^^^                 ^^^^^^
//  1                     2
```

You are expecting (1) to refer to the global variable `weight` that you defined elsewhere, and (2) to refer to the local variable `weight`. I hope you see how this causes a problem.

In fact, the local variable is always assumed instead of the global. Solution: use different names.